# Vertex AI Pipelines. Batch Prediction 'Error state: 5.'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines

I have been trying to run a Vertex AI pipeline using Kubeflow Pipelines and the google-cloud-pipeline-components library. The pipeline is entirely custom container components with the exception of the batch predictions.

The code for my pipeline is of the following form:

```
# GCP infrastructure resources
from google.cloud import aiplatform, storage
from google_cloud_pipeline_components import aiplatform as gcc_aip

# kubeflow resources
import kfp
from kfp.v2 import dsl, compiler
from kfp.v2.dsl import component, pipeline

train_container_uri = '<insert custom docker image in gcr for training code>'

@pipeline(name="<pipeline name>", pipeline_root=pipeline_root_path)
def my_ml_pipeline():
    # run the preprocessing workflow using a custom kfp component and get the outputs

    preprocess_op = preprocess_component()
    
    train_path, test_path =  preprocess_op.outputs['Train Data'], preprocess_op.outputs['Test Data']
    
    # path to string for gcs uri containing train data
    train_path_text = preprocess_op.outputs['Train Data GCS Path']
    
    # create training dataset on Vertex AI from the preprocessing outputs
    train_set_op = gcc_aip.TabularDatasetCreateOp(
        project='<insert gcs project id>', 
        display_name='<insert display name>', location='us-west1', 
        gcs_source = train_path_text
        )
    
    train_set = train_set_op.outputs['dataset']
    
    # custom training op
    training_op = gcc_aip.CustomContainerTrainingJobRunOp(
        project='<insert gcp project id>', 
        display_name='<insert display name>', 
        location='us-west1',
        dataset=train_set, 
        container_uri=train_container_uri, 
        staging_bucket=bucket_name,
        model_serving_container_image_uri='us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/prediction/tf2-gpu.2-11:latest',
        model_display_name='<insert model name>',
        machine_type='n1-standard-4')
    
    model_output = training_op.outputs['model']
    
    # batch prediction op    
    batch_prediction_op = gcc_aip.ModelBatchPredictOp(
        project='<insert gcp project id>', 
        job_display_name='<insert name of job>', 
        location='us-west1', 
        model=model_output, 
        gcs_source_uris=['gs://<bucket name>/<directory>/name_of_file.csv'], 
        instances_format='csv', 
        gcs_destination_output_uri_prefix='gs://<bucket name>/<directory>/',
        machine_type='n1-standard-4', 
        accelerator_count=2, 
        accelerator_type='NVIDIA_TESLA_P100')
```

(For security and non-disclosure reasons, I can't input any specific paths or gcp projects, just trust that I inputted those correctly)

My initial preprocessing and training components seem to work fine (model is uploaded to registry, training job succeeded, preprocessed data appears in GCS buckets as *seemingly* necessary). However, my pipeline fails to finish when it gets to the batch prediction phase.

The error log terminates with the following error:

`ValueError: Job failed with value error in error state: 5.`

Additionally, I have a picture of the logs (the traceback only contains references to the `google-cloud-pipeline-components` library, none of my specific code). This is seen here:

[image]

This error is presumably within the scope of the `ModelBatchPredictOp()` method.

I don't even know where to begin, but could anyone give any pointers as to what error state 5 means? I know it's a `ValueError` so it must have received either an invalid value in the method or in the model. However, I've ran the model on the exact same dataset locally, so I assume that it is an invalid input into the method. However, I have checked every input into the `ModelBatchPredictOp()`. Has anyone gotten this error state before? Any help is appreciated.

Using `google-cloud-pipeline-components==1.0.42`, `google-cloud-aiplatform==1.24.1`, `kfp==1.8.18`. My model is trained on TensorFlow 2.11.1, Python 3.10 in both my custom docker images and the script used to run the pipeline. Thank you in advance!

**Edit 1 (2023-05-10)**:

I've looked up on the GitHub repo, it seems that my `ValueError` has the following description:

```
 // Some requested entity (e.g., file or directory) was not found.
  //
  // Note to server developers: if a request is denied for an entire class
  // of users, such as gradual feature rollout or undocumented allowlist,
  // `NOT_FOUND` may be used. If a request is denied for some users within
  // a class of users, such as user-based access control, `PERMISSION_DENIED`
  // must be used.
  //
  // HTTP Mapping: 404 Not Found
  NOT_FOUND = 5;
```

(The error code is detailed here https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/rpc/code.proto)

(The exception leading to my error message was surfaced here https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/components/google-cloud/google_cloud_pipeline_components/container/v1/gcp_launcher/job_remote_runner.py)

Now the question is, where in my `ModelBatchPredictOp()` is a file or directory missing? I've checked to make sure that all of these gcs paths that I've inputted are correct and lead to the expected locations. Any further thoughts?

**Edit 2 (2023-05-10):**

I noticed that the output of the `ModelBatchPredictOp()` component throws me a json detailing some errors. This is what the error body is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "aiplatform.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.cloud.aiplatform.v1.JobService.GetBatchPredictionJob"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, I have provided the necessary IAM roles to every relevant service agent/account (according to this: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/access-control). So still trying to figure out where my pipeline is missing credentials. This is consistent with the original error code, however. Since `Error state: 5.` means a directory/file can't be found, it makes sense that missing credentials would cause this error state. However, I am not aware what IAM roles/permissions I am missing in my service account/agents. Another update to be expected soon.

**Edit 3 (2023-05-10)**

I don't have a solution yet, but I do have another clue of what's going on. All of my batch predictions have been timing out after 18-20 minutes (huge variance but oh well). I think that the model is actually performing the batch predictions properly, but it is not **able to write the predictions to the destination bucket**. This makes sense because the batch prediction job fails after 20 minutes every single run. I think that whatever code writes the predictions to the bucket has insufficient permissions to perform this write.

The only issue now is that I still don't know where I am supposed to provision the appropriate credentials to perform this write after the batch prediction completes.

Comment: Could you try running the batch prediction with your own [custom service account](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/main/docs/README.rst#batch-prediction) with enough permission? Let me know if this helps you or not.

Comment: @kiranmathew unfortunately, it didn’t work /: I even tried running batch predictions directly from the google console instead of through the SDK’s and it still didn’t work, same error message. That must mean that it’s not an issue with the SDK’s, it has to be an issue with either my trained model or my data. However, my model seems to be training properly. Maybe it’s an issue with something in my batch prediction input data?

Comment: @kiranmathew I have added more updates on what I've been finding out, to the original post. So far, this is not an SDK issue. I confirmed this by trying out the Kubeflow pipeline component (what I detailed in the post above), trying out the direct method that you linked, and using the UI to create a batch prediction job. All of these failed with the same error. So this points me to this being a permission error. However, I configured a service account with (seemingly) the correct IAM roles. Do you think there any more stones left to turn?

Comment: Hi @AndrewJaeyoung, As I mentioned in the above comment,can you try with the batch_predict() instead of ModelBatchPredictOp()  because based on my understanding ModelBatchPredictOp() does not support the custom service account ?

Comment: @kiranmathew Sorry if I didn't make it clear, but I've tried all 3 options: 1) using ModelBatchPredictOp() in the KFP pipeline 2) using model.batch_predict() via the Vertex AI SDK with a custom service account 3) creating a batch prediction for a model via the GCP console (under the Batch Prediction tab in Vertex AI). They all result in the same error.

Comment: Hi @AndrewJaeyoung, is it possible for you to use [aiplatform](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/main/docs/README.rst#importing) instead of ‘google_cloud_pipeline_components`  in your full code? Also, use the custom service account during prediction.

Comment: @kiranmathew I already tried using aiplatform sdk (the one that you linked) instead of google_cloud_pipeline_components (model.batch_predict() is an aiplatform method for the model object). And as stated earlier, I am invoking the batch prediction via aiplatform, with a custom service account that has full access to my bucket, as well as the following IAM roles: 

- Service Account Admin
- Service Account Token Creator
- Storage Object Admin
- Vertex AI Administrator
- Vertex AI Custom Code Service Agent

Same errors as when I run with the pipeline...

Comment: Hi @AndrewJaeyoung, Could you give the Vertex AI  Service Agent  role also to your custom service account? Please try with the latest version of the aiplatform. If this also does not solve your issue, I recommend you to create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/) if you have a support plan. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: @kiranmathew Appreciate your help, I solved this issue. I detailed it as an answer to this post. Permissions on my service account were not the issue.

Comment: Hi @AndrewJaeyoung, I am glad to hear that your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I was originally going to edit my post, but for the sake of marking the trail for future Vertex AI users, I will put this as an answer.

My initial problem here was that I did not use the correct serialization format for my model. I am using a custom-trained tensorflow model (specifically a tf.keras model), and I mistakenly used the `.h5` format instead of the TensorFlow SavedModel format. Why this threw a 404 Not Found Error is beyond my understanding. The error message surrounding the incorrect serialization format needs to be MUCH clearer.

The reason why I figured this out was that I tried to deploy this model to an endpoint for online predictions. This errored out with the following message:

```
Vertex AI <noreply-vertexai@google.com>
Mon, May 15, 3:49 PM (2 days ago)
to me

Hello Vertex AI Customer,

Due to an error, Vertex AI was unable to create 
endpoint "test_endpoint_appmkt1".
Additional Details:
Operation State: Failed with errors
Resource Name: 
projects/971627237637/locations/us-west1/endpoints/910580345751994368
Error Messages: Model artifact directory is expected to contain exactly one 
of: [saved_model.pb, saved_model.pbtxt]. Please re-upload the Model with 
correct artifact directory.
```

This made me realize that the pre-built tensorflow prediction containers likely **only recognize the TensorFlow SavedModel format**.

Furthermore, if you are using a tensorflow.keras model, make sure that your batch prediction inputs are formatted correctly.

The request body for an online prediction on a tf.keras model should look as follows:

```
{"instances": [
    {"<name of input layer1>": <input values of the appropriate shape>, 
     "<name of input layer2>": <input values of the appropriate shape>, ...},
    <repeat the format of the previous element in this list for your next record, etc...>
]}
```

Each dictionary in the value associated to "instances" is a single record. The "" is taken from the output of `model.summary()`.

For **batch predictions**, you need to input a `.jsonl` file. This file will be processed by the batch prediction service into a request body that looks like the above request body for online predictions. However, the jsonl file will need to contain each dictionary in the value associated to "instances" in the following way:

```
# COMMENT: for record 1
{"<name of input layer1>": <input values of the appropriate shape>, 
     "<name of input layer2>": <input values of the appropriate shape>, ...}
# COMMENT: for record 2
{"<name of input layer1>": <input values of the appropriate shape>, 
     "<name of input layer2>": <input values of the appropriate shape>, ...}
# COMMENT: for record 3
{"<name of input layer1>": <input values of the appropriate shape>, 
     "<name of input layer2>": <input values of the appropriate shape>, ...}
# etc...
```

Note: this is if you use the **pre-built** tensorflow prediction container from Google. The input format is consistent with the input formats necessary for TensorFlow Serving.

If anyone in the future has similar issues with batch predictions in Vertex AI, please comment here and I will do my best to share what possible workarounds could be. Google's documentation surrounding Vertex AI is absolutely horrendous, and GCP customer support tries their best but is typically not able to help in a timely manner.